# laravel- eloquent relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have a courses table, a course `hasMany` sections and sections `hasMany` lectures and lectures `hasMany` comments. How should I define the relationship in the `LectureComment` model, if I have a comment id and I want to know its course name?

***table structures***

courses: `id|title`

sections: `id|course_id|name`

lectures: `id|section_id|name|description`

lecture_comments: `id|lecture_id|user_id|comment_body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In course model:

```
public function sections()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Section');
}
```

Section model:

```
public function course()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Course');
}

public function lectures()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Lecture');
}
```

Lecture model:

```
public function section()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Section');
}

public function lectures_comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\LecturesComment');
}
```

LecturesComment model:

```
public function lecture()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Lecture');
}
```

To receive required data, you must walk through relations.

If you have correctly written foreign keys, this code will return a course title:

```
$comment = LecturesComment::find(1);

$courseName = $comment->lecture->section->course->title
```

Hope it will be helpful :)